# Minimum number of non-coplanar forces required to keep an object in equilibrium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, linear-algebra, equilibrium

> The minimum number of non-coplanar forces that can keep a particle in equilibrium is:
>
> (a) 1
>
> (b) 2
>
> (c) 3
>
> (d) 4

Answer given is option $(d)$ , i.e $4$. But can’t it be $(c)$ , i.e $3$ too?

Suppose I have three forces:

$F_1= 3i +4j$

$F_2= -3i +5k$

$F_3= -4j -5k$

$F_1$ lies in x-y plane, $F_2$ in x-z plane and $F_3$ in z-y plane. So all of them are non coplanar. But sum of all of them results in $0$. So shouldn’t three forces be enough to keep an object in equilibrium?

Comment: Shouldn't zero forces be enough to keep an object in an equilibrium (sometimes called an indifferent equilibrium)? Aside from that counting the number of forces is quite badly defined operation in general. Or does a single zero force vector count as one force?

Comment: All three of your chosen vectors lie in the same plane, $20x - 15y + 12z = 0$

Comment: @notovny I realised that later. My bad. Sorry

Comment: @SebastianRiese I don't know. This stuff hasn't been taught to me yet so I can't say anything

Comment: ANY three points define a plane.  It takes a minimum of 4 points to become non-planar.

Comment: @DavidWhite That's not how I'd interpret the meaning of coplanar for vectors. Would you consider the three canonical basis vectors as coplanar? They sure are coplanar when interpreted as points in affine space, but in the context of vectors I'd interpret coplanar as meaning $\dim \text{span}({\vec v_1, \ldots, \vec v_n}) \le 2$ (of course that defeats my argument of zero forces as well, because usually the span of the empty set is taken to be the zero vector ... so having a dimension less than two).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the forces $\vec{F_1}, \vec{F_2}, \vec{F_3}$ defined by the points $(3,4,0)$ , $(-3,0,5)$ and $(0,-4,-5)$ are coplanar.

Even though $\vec{F_1}, \vec{F_2}, \vec{F_3}$ algebraically sum to $\vec 0$ they are nevertheless coplanar.

In fact, if you do a little algebra (solve three simultaneous equations) or calculate the cross product $(\vec{F_2}-\vec{F_1})\times (\vec{F_3}-\vec{F_1})$ (which gives you the vector normal to this plane) you deduce that $(3,4,0)$, $(-3,0,5)$ and $(0,-4,-5)$ lie on the plane defined by the equation $$20x-15y+12z=0$$

So the rule still holds and you would actually need $3+1$ non coplanar forces for equilibrium, where the forth force would need to be equal and opposite to the sum of the first three  forces.

Note that three coplanar forces, or even two coplanar forces can sum to zero.

Comment: Could you please explain why the addition is wrong. As per my understanding all those forces are acting on one point, i.e the origin. (3,4,0),(-3,0,5) and (0-4,-5) are the heads of the vectors.

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Add-or-Subtract-Vectors the first method in the article is the method that our teacher has taught us.

Comment: Then why is gravitational force acting on an object on an inclined plane drawn like this https://images.app.goo.gl/rW2xB88uE94ZLpEK8

Comment: I was just trying to correlate the diagram with my question. what I mean is that , just assume that the three forces in the diagram are the three forces from my question, all of them have their heads in different directions but they originate from the same point right? This means that they act on the same point right?

Comment: I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: And also I've realised now that the three forces I took are actually coplanar. So the very premise of my question itself is wrong

Comment: This also probably means that it doesn't matter if the forces lie on mutually orthogonal planes because if F1 was just î, F2 was j^ and F3 was k^, then the resultant will be I + j+ k.  And a fourth force will be needed to cancel this resultant. So this means that 4 forces are needed to keep an object at equilibrium even if the forces lie on mutually orthogonal planes. The entire problem cropped up because I had wrongly assumed that the forces are non coplanar, when in fact they're actually coplanar.

Answer (score 2):

The question seems to be worded incorrectly.

- If there is a known applied force, then 3  force magnitudes are linearly independent directions are needed to oppose the force. I can see that 3+1 would be the answer *if you include the applied force*.
- Or one single force in opposite direction and magnitude if the directions are arbitrary. In this case, the answer is 1+1.

The issue that I have is that it is nowhere stated that there is one force acting on the particle. There could be 12 forces acting, and needed 3 reaction directions to keep stable for an answer of 12+3 = 15. The situation is very ambiguous as stated.

Comment: I did not understand the second bullet point. Wouldn't that case become coplanar?

Comment: @Obinna Technically yes not just coplanar, but coincident also. But I don't understand why the need for counting the applied force in the answer.

Comment: We are not counting the applied force right? There are 3 non coplanar forces and one force to cancel their resultant